# libPd and c++ wrapper implementation

Tags: c++, puredata

I'm trying to use libPd, the wrapper for PureData.
But the documentation is poor and I'm not very into C++
Do you know how I can simply send a floating value to a Pd patch?

Do I need to install libPd or I can just include the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to send a value to a running instance of Pd (the standalone application), you could do so via Pd's networking facilities.

e.g.

```
[netreceive 65432 1]
|
[route value]
|
[print]
```

will receive data sent from the cmdline via:

```
echo "value 1.234567;" | pdsend 65432 localhost udp
```

you can also send multiple values at once, e.g.

```
echo "value 1.234567 3.141592;" | pdsend 65432 localhost udp
```

if you find `pdsend` to slow for your purposes (e.g. if you launch the executable for each message you want to send you have a considerable overhead!), you could construct the message directly in your application and use an ordinary UDP-socket to send *FUDI*-messages to Pd.

FUDI-messages really are simple text strings, with atoms separated by whitespace and a terminating semicolon, e.g.

```
accelerator 1.23 3.14 2.97; button 1;
```

you might also considering using OSC, but for this you will need some externals (OSC by mrpeach; net by mrpeach (or iemnet)) on the Pd side.

as for performance, i've been using the latter with complex tracking data (hundreds of values per frame at 125fps) and for streaming multichannel audio, so i don't think this is a problem.

if you are already using libPd and only want to communicate from the host-application, use Adam's solution (but your question is a bit vague about that, so i'm including this answer just in case)

Comment: Thank You, but even using UDP is too slow.
I need to read values from an IR Distance sensor, when I use just one sensor the speed is ok, but when I use two sensors the speed is no more acceptable.

Comment: in this case i think that the problem is *not* on the Pd side but rather on the sending side - e.g. the call overhead of `pdsend`. i've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks, I'm trying using OSCpack but when I compile example codes I get: "SimpleSend.cpp:5:41: fatal error: osc/OscOutboundPacketStream.h: No such file or directory"
It's very strange because the file is there!
Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: @Wateredge obviously your compiler is not looking "there" but somewhere else. the simple answer is to use `-I` to specify the search directories for the compiler; but you should probably *install* OSCpack *properly* (if that's possible on your system); but how to compile against a given library is not really related to the original question

Answer (score 5):

First of all, check out [ofxpd](https://github.com/danomatika/ofxPd). It has an excellent libpd implementaiton with OpenFrameworks. If you are starting with C++ you may want to start with [OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/) since it has some great documentation and nice integration with Pd via the ofxpd extension.

There are two good references for getting started with libpd (though neither cover C++ in too much detail): [the original article](http://www.uni-weimar.de/medien/wiki/images/Embedding_Pure_Data_with_libpd.pdf) and [Peter Brinkmann's book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022503.do).

On the libpd wiki there is a p[age for getting started with libpd](https://github.com/libpd/libpd/wiki/C---Wrapper-for-libpd). The linked project at the bottom has some code snippets in main.cpp that demonstrate how to send floats to your Pd patch.

```
pd.sendBang("fromCPP");
pd.sendFloat("fromCPP", 100);
pd.sendSymbol("fromCPP", "test string");
```

In your Pd patch you'll set up a [receive fromCPP] and then these messages will register in your patch.

In order to get the print output you have to use the receivers from libpd in order to receiver the strings and then do something with them. libpd comes with PdBase, which is a great class for getting libpd up and running. PdBase has sendBang, sendFloat, sendMessage, and also has the receivers set up so that you can get output from your Pd patch.

Comment: Thank You for your answer, i'm trying to compile the sample C code in the libPd folder (just to try) and I get "z_libpd.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated."

Comment: I'm compiling using "sudo gcc pdtest.c -o pdtest". I've tried to use "sudo make install" in the libPd folder, but it says "make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop." Thanks